# Matlab Error: Matrix dimensions must agree

Tags: matlab

cant seem to figure the error. Any pointers please.

**Code**

```
alpha=30:40:70;
t=[1 6 11 16 21 26 31];
x=cos(alpha.*(t));
```

**Error Message:**

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in r_t_demo (line 22)
x=cosd(alpha).*t;
```

Comment: Please always try to construct a _minimal_ version as I have done now for you, see [mcve].

Comment: Which result do you expect? A `2x7` matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Your alpha  = [30,70] while your t=[1 6 11 16 21 26 31];
You can do an element wise multiplication if the two arrays are of the same length or if one of them has just one element. You cannot do an element wise multiplication between two arrays of different lengths.